# dont work staticfiles on prod (django docker nginx)

Tags: django, docker, nginx

help!

I containerize my Django app, but static files in debug=false have 404. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
django_gunicorn_1  | Not Found: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
django_gunicorn_1  | Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
etc
```

dockerfile for django

```
FROM python:3.9.0-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["./commondev", "./requirements.txt", "./entrypoint.sh", "./"]
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

and for Nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: DEFAULT.CONF FRO NGINX

Comment: version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"

  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

Comment: nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

volumes:
  static_volume: